# Python Function about Logistic Equation

Tags: python, function, for-loop, while-loop

The original logistic function that represents the change in population size per year is delta_N=r*(1-N/K)*N. I'm trying to write a new function that takes in r, K, N0 (The initial value of N, which stands for initial population size), and t (the number of years) and return the population N after t years. Below is my code. it does work but when I plug in t=0 (which is supposed to mean there is no change in time), it stills return some N that is different from N0 (which means my code is likely wrong?). Do people have any idea as to how I can fix my code?

```
def equation2(r,K,N0,t):
    i=0
    N=N0
    while i<=t:
        Nf=N+(r*(1-N/K)*N)
        N=Nf 
        i=i+1
    return Nf
```

Comment: In your own words, what does `i <= t` mean? What do you expect to happen when `i == 0` and `t == 0`? Therefore, if you "plug in t=0", given that the first thing  that happens in the function is `i=0`, how many times will the loop run? How many times *should* it run? Do you see the problem?

Comment: Yes. I see what you mean. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see 2 potential problems with your code:

1. Plugging in t = 0 for your function will still go inside your `while` loop once because it will check for `0<=0` Which is `true`. You need to remove the `=` sign from your condition
2. After fixing this, `Nf` will be undefined when passing in t = 0. This also needs to be dealt with accordingly

```
    def equation2(r,K,N0,t):
        i=0
        N=N0
        while i<t:
            N += (r*(1-N/K)*N) 
            i=i+1
        return N
```